# slideToggle only the clicked button

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="button-collapse" >
    collapsible
</button> </br>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Sample text
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button-collapse").click(function() {
        $(".collapse").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

My code is pretty straightforward. I want to create a "show/hide/toggle" div. How can I achieve this so that only the one div with the corresponding button toggles? Right now all my divs toggle. I don't wish to assign unique ids to my html elements either because toggle elements will be created dynamicly later with php.

Comment: can you define " the one div with the corresponding button " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).nextAll('div.collapse:first')`, which will get the first next occurrence of `div.collapse`.

`.next()` won't work as the next immediate sibling is a line break (`<br />`);

```
$(".button-collapse").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('div.collapse:first').slideToggle();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6DKc/6/)

Comment: maybe a side question here, how did you figure about that :first pseudo selector? Is that a CSS trick?

Comment: It's just a pseudo class unique to jQuery - [see here](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.next()` to target the next element. Try this:

```
 $(".button-collapse").click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use first button of nextAll like below

```
$(".button-collapse").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".collapse:first").slideToggle();
 });
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/25/)